# Rsyslog property Replace

Tags: mysql, rsyslog

i am trying to take logs from my routers for traffic monitoring using rsyslog + Mysql, i am receiving this type of message from router.

**`in:<pppoe-username> out:eth0, proto TCP (ACK), 10.xx.xx.xx:8020->43.xx.xx.xx:443, NAT (10.xx.xx.xx:8020->103.xx.xx.xx:8020)->43.xx.xx.xx:443, len 52`**

I was wondering if it's possible to breakdown this logs like

```
Username : in:<pppoe-username>
Interface : out:eth0 
Protocol : proto TCP (ACK)
Source IP : 10.xx.xx.xx:8020
Destination IP : 43.xx.xx.xx:443
NAT : 103.xx.xx.xx:8020
```

i wanted to use property Replace but i didn understand the DOC, can anyone help me out with some example so that i can understand it easily.

Thanks a bunch